# Form Based Authentication giving Forbidden 403

Tags: java, security, jsf, forms-authentication

Hey im making an application where the username and password have to be stored in the glassfish server and then when i run the application the user has to enter already stored user name and password to continue.  But when the credentials are entered correctly i get HTTP Status 403 - Forbidden.  I cant figure it out ive been working on it for two days now.  Can someone help me please...
Here is my code:

Login Page

```
<form action="j_security_check" method=post>
    <p><strong>Please Enter Your User Name: </strong>
    <input type="text" name="j_username" size="25">
    <p><p><strong>Please Enter Your Password: </strong>
    <input type="password" size="25" name="j_password">
    <p><p>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    <input type="reset" value="Reset">
    </form>
```

Web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <login-config>
    <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
    <realm-name>file</realm-name>
    <form-login-config>
        <form-login-page>/loginform.html</form-login-page>
        <form-error-page>/loginerror.html</form-error-page>
    </form-login-config>
</login-config>
<security-role>
    <role-name>Administrator</role-name>
</security-role>
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Protected Area</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/faces/index.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>Administrator</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>faces/index.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

sun-web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE sun-web-app PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Application Server 9.0 Servlet 2.5//EN" "http://www.sun.com/software/appserver/dtds/sun-web-app_2_5-0.dtd">
<sun-web-app error-url="">
  <context-root>/</context-root>
  <security-role-mapping>
    <role-name>Administrator</role-name>
    <group-name>Administrator</group-name>
  </security-role-mapping>
  <class-loader delegate="true"/>
  <jsp-config>
    <property name="keepgenerated" value="true">
      <description>Keep a copy of the generated servlet class' java code.</description>
    </property>
  </jsp-config>
</sun-web-app>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I suspect that `j_security_check` is not a valid URL/relative URL.

Comment: Stupid Question but where do i figure out where it points too.  Im only new to javaServerFaces and im pretty cluless...

Comment: I'm not familiar with JSF (you should re-tag this question in order to attract the right people) but I think that web.xml is the right place (which you did check). If you copied this example from somewhere - try to search the code and see if you missed anything.

Comment: retagged... Ye i have the solution i downloaded working perfectly, its when im trying to implement it into my own code but im positive i didnt forget anything...

Comment: if anyone found the answer, please post it. I am also facing same problem with apache tomcat server